# iheartquotes API dont return JSON with source option?

Tags: json, api

I am try making a request to:

```
http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?source=joel_on_software?format=json
```

but the result come with text format (ignored json format), but with this request:

```
http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?format=json
```

Everything works fine.

Can someone tell me why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am make wrong request: correct one: http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?format=json&source=joel_on_software